# Simple URL Picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

hi my scenario is I want to give the user the ability to browse SharePoint for a file and then the dialog should give me back the URL of that file.
Is this simple? And how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to the AssetUrlSector control from SharePoint.

You can find the MSDN article at 
[AssetUrlSelector class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.asseturlselector.aspx)

Sample code for the control:

```
<CMS:AssetUrlSelector
  ID="assetSelectedImage"
  CssTextBox="ms-input ms-assetimagedialog-longtextbox"
  UseImageAssetPicker="true"
  MaxLength="512"
  DecodeUrlPath="false"
  AccessibilityName="<%$Resources:cms, asseteditimage_selectedimage_label%>"
  runat="server"
  AllowExternalUrls="false"
  ValidateUrl="true" />
```

Where CMS is:

```
<%@ Register
  TagPrefix="CMS"
  Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls"
  Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Hope this helps.